# How to show total of columns at footer in RadGrid Telerik

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid

How to show total of columns at RadGrid footer in Telerik?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-totals-in-footers.html).

Answer (score 5):

You need to bind to the ItemDataBound event:

```
int counter = 0;

void Grid_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.WebControls.GridItemEventArgs e) {
      if(e.Item is GridDataItem) {
         GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
         counter += Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["SomeField"].Text);
      }
      else if(e.Item is GridFooterItem) {
         GridFooterItem footerItem = e.Item as GridFooterItem;
         FooterItem["YourFooterColumn"].Text = counter.ToString();
      }
 }
```

Comment: @shirish: if this answer is good for you, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The solution which was given by Erik is also working.
But Radgrid have inbuilt column for this.

```
<telerik:GridCalculatedColumn HeaderText="Total Price" UniqueName="TotalPrice" DataType="System.Double"
                    DataFields="UnitPrice, UnitsInStock" Expression="{0}*{1}" FooterText="Total : "
                    Aggregate="Sum" />
```

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/calculatedcolumns/defaultcs.aspx